# Proper way to select by related object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to ask, what is a proper way to select books from given shelf

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :shelf
end

class Shelf < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :books
end
```

Using `Book.where(:shelf => shelf)` raises exception like `no such column: book.shelf`. I know I can reverse it, like `shelf.books` but this won't work if there is need to filter by more than one object. All I could find is that query should looks like `Books.where(:shelf_id => shelf.id)` but this doesn't seem very DRY or even a bit cool..

Comment: What do you mean by 'if there is need to filter by more than one object.'? Do you need to chain the conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use joins or includes :

```
Book.joins(:shelfs) # will load all the Books that have one Shelf

Book.includes(:shelfs) # will load all the Books and Shelfs even if the book has no Shelf associated

# or beginning with a Shelf object:
@shelf.books # will return all Book where shelf_id = @shelf.id
```

If you need precisions / have questions, don't hesitate to comment ;) (I'm thinking of you phrase *"like shelf.books but this won't work if there is need to filter by more than one object."* which I don't really understand)

Comment: if a book belongs to category, just like to a shelf, and you want to find books from certains shelf and of certain category :)
And I need books from certain shelf (the shelf object is created somewhere else, doesn't matter).

Comment: so `joins` them: `Book.joins(:categories).joins(:shelfs).where('categories.name = ? AND shelfs.id = ?', 'CategoryName', my_shelf_id)`

Answer (score 0):

For relational dryness, have a peek at [delegation](http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/05/law-of-demeter-and-forwardable.html), where references from one model to another are encapsulated within one of the models. There's quite some discussion on whether or not this is a solution to a real problem, I personally believe it can be, but decide for yourself. The article is old but not outdated.